# How to make a Base component that will allow other components to inherit new functionality or code from it in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, inheritance, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Component 1:-

```
<template>
<blur :isData="isData">
 
    <!-- logic/implementation of component 1 -->
    <div>
    
    </div>


</blur>
<template>

<script>

import blur from "../shared/Blur";

 name: "component-1",
  components: {
    blur,
  },

</script>
```

Just like this `component1.vue`, I have multiple components which are using `blur` component. Is it possible that instead of writing and importing `blur` in every single component, I can make some base class that can transfer the blur functionality in every single component in the folder. Can something like this be achieved in vue ?